# 512 bits multiplication on assembly language

Tags: assembly

here is my code and i am getting two errors in it. I am beginner in the language so please help me out.this is my code.

```
org 100h

jmp start

num1: dw 15
num2: dw 7
result: dw 0000
temp: dw 0000 

start:  xor ax,ax
    mov cx,64
    xor bx,bx
here:   mov [result+bx],ax
    add bx,2
    loop here

    mov cx,32
    xor bx,bx
here1:  mov ax,[bx+num1]
    mov [temp+bx],ax
    add bx,2
    loop here1

    xor ax,ax
    mov cx,32
here2:  mov [temp+bx],ax
    add bx,2
    loop here2

    mov cx,32
there:  push cx
    mov cx,32
    mov bx,32
    clc
here3:  rcr [num2+bx]
    dec bx
    dec bx
    loop here3
    jnc skipadd

    xor bx,bx
    mov cx,64
    clc
here4:  mov ax,[temp+bx]
    adc [result+bx],ax
    inc bx
    inc bx
    loop here4

skipadd:xor bx,bx
    mov cx,64
    clc
here5:  rcl [temp+bx]
    inc bx
    inc bx
    loop here5

    pop ax,
    loop there

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
```

Comment: And what are those errors? None of us are psychic here.

Comment: just like your result and temp, num1 and num2 are 16-bit. are you sure your input is provided in those nums?

Comment: Pleas edit your question and add a tag for your processor architecture. I could guess at [tag:x86] but I shouldn't *have* to guess. There's more than one type of processor in the world and they have different assembly languages.

Comment: What do you mean by "512 bits multiplication"?  Multiplying 512 bit numbers?  Multiplying 2 256 bit numbers into a 512 bit number?

Answer (score 1):

This code is overwriting the program!!!

```
num1: dw 15
num2: dw 7
result: dw 0000
temp: dw 0000 

start:  xor ax,ax
    mov cx,64
    xor bx,bx
here:   mov [result+bx],ax
    add bx,2
    loop here
```

You need to change the definition of *result* and *temp* to allow for 64 words.

```
result: dw 64 dup (0)
temp:   dw 64 dup (0)
```

You are copying garbage with the following

```
    mov cx,32
    xor bx,bx
here1:  mov ax,[bx+num1]
    mov [temp+bx],ax
    add bx,2
    loop here1
```

Better use

```
    mov cx,32
    xor bx,bx
    mov ax,[bx+num1]
here1:  mov [temp+bx],ax
    add bx,2
    loop here1
```